# how to access to properity in usercontrol from html

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have public property in user control and i need access to this property from HTML for parent for this user control

```
Public Property ActorID As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)
        ViewState("ActorID") = value
    End Set
    Get
        Return ViewState("ActorID")
    End Get
End Property


<uc3:Hos_Applicants ID="Hos_Applicants1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: What do you mean for parent for this control ?

Comment: @gefrag the page it has the user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<uc3:Hos_Applicants ID="Hos_Applicants1" runat="server" ActorID="2" />
```

you can access to property and set value in user control from parent asp page